# How to install SSL certificate of endpoint URL in Websphere application server

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8, websphere-portal

I have to install ssl certificate of endpoint url in WAS. The certificate I generated from openssl command using hostname and port number of end point. The generate certificate format is *.cert. 
WAS version is 8.5.5.14. Please help me on this. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This functionality can be provided directly from WAS Console:

Follow the path **"Security"> "SSL certificate and key management" > "Key stores and certificates" > "CellDefaultTrustStore"(or NodeDefaultTrustStore) > Signer certificates**, then press the button **"Retrieve from port"**, enter the hostname/IP Address and the port of the remote SSL Host, declare an alias for this certificate.

Finally press **"Retrieve Signer information"** and Apply/Save.

Comment: Tried your solution **Connection timed out (Connection timed out)**  error is getting after clicking **Retrieve Signer information**

Comment: Seems like a networking problem, may be a firewall is between your WAS and the remote server?